# Defining private params for an included launch file with multiple namespaces

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way for defining private parameters for an included launch file that has multiple private namespaces? My scenario is that I have three PID modules running in parallel that uses three identical node types but with different namespaces and parameter mappings. The topic remapping arguments are in the private namespace for the nodes.

There is no mention of this situation on [Roslaunch tips for larger projects](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20tips%20for%20larger%20projects).

There is mention of a similar scenario in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/60343/how-to-remap-a-topic-to-sub-namespaces/).

Do I need to do something like passing topic remappings as a series of defined `$(arg ...)` constructs?

Thanks,
Bart

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182926/defining-private-params-for-an-included-launch-file-with-multiple-namespaces/) by [bjem85](https://answers.ros.org/users/18596/bjem85/) on ROS Answers with karma: 163 on 2014-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

args sounds like the right way to go. For more information provide a concrete example on what you want to do.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0